# Write Spark Stream to Phoenix table

Tags: apache-spark, hbase, spark-structured-streaming, apache-phoenix, spark-streaming-kafka

I am trying to figure out how to write a Spark Stream to a Phoenix table in the least convoluted way.

So far I have only found this solution: [kafka-to-phoenix](https://community.cloudera.com/t5/Community-Articles/Spark-Streaming-Explained-Kafka-to-Phoenix/ta-p/245778), which requires some deep ad-hoc engineering (to my noob eyes).
I can tailor the linked solution to my needs without major issues, but I wonder if there are better solutions out there.

Basically, I arrive at this point in my code:

```
streamingData
    .writeStream
    .option("checkpointLocation", checkpointLocation)
    .trigger(Trigger.ProcessingTime(triggerInterval, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS))
    .foreach(
        howToInsertToPhoenix?()
    )
    .start()
    .awaitTermination()
```

I have a running solution dumping the data to HBase, but it's not really less convoluted with the proposed Phoenix one, so it's not easily/promptly generalizable for similar use cases.

Many thanks in advance :)